# Angular formly with angular ui bootstrap typeahead dynamic options

Tags: angular-formly

I am trying to get angular formly and angular ui bootstrap typeahead playing nice. What I want is to have my select list populated from an http get request, and each time there is a change to the select field it should fire a function to get a new list of options.

```
typeahead="address for address in getLocation($viewValue)"
```

I'm not sure I did the jsbin right, but here we go.

[JsBin of my problem](http://jsbin.com/tagare/edit?html,js,output)

Here is a plunker with the typeahead working alone.

[dynamic typeahead works here](http://plnkr.co/edit/HoKXYjgHRNOzkwBMR0su?p=preview)

I can't even get the getLocation function to fire. I have tried vm.getLocation, but no dice.

Help would be very appreciated!

Thanks. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

[Async select options](http://angular-formly.com/#/example/other/async-select-options-with-controller)
[Watchers Example](http://angular-formly.com/#/example/field-options/watchers)

Initially the options should be an empty array, and passed in with as shown above. Then you need to add a watcher that updates the $scope.options.templateOptions.options as its called.

But, I am still having trouble getting the typeahead to answer functions. In the typeahead docs you can use a callback to know when it is selected.

```
typeahead-on-select='onSelect($item, $model, $label)'
```

My onSelect function in the controller is never called.

Comment: Those are two separate links.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example...I combined the Async formly example with the UI Bootstrap example...notice it now becomes item.question for item instead of item for item...

Unsure why that is, I checked and its the same format the Async example is coming back as...tried all kinds of ways to get it to display the full JSON object but no luck...

if I set it to item for item, the whole JSON object shows in the model but the search returns [object Object], otherwise its only the single line which I have set to the label, which I guess is the same way it displays normally, so that's OK...

Anyway, it works

http://plnkr.co/IjuJ0HPGCKfZAOrK0u3z?p=preview

```
      app.run(function(formlyConfig) {
          formlyConfig.setType({
              name: 'typeahead',
              template: '<input type="text" ng-model="model[options.templateOptions.label]" uib-typeahead="item.question for item in to.options | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:15" class="form-control">',
              wrapper: ['bootstrapLabel', 'bootstrapHasError'],
    });
  });
```